# Form Missalignment

Tags: rider, c#-7.0

I create a Form and set a specific size and when I run the program the displayed form doesn't match the previously set size.

For example I create a Form and I add a panel with size 100x100. Then I set the size of the Form to 200x200. When I start the program the displayed form should be 200x200 and the panel should occupy exactly 1/4 of it but here this clearly isn't the case.

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        Panel actionPanel = new Panel();
        actionPanel.Size = new Size(100, 100);
        actionPanel.BackColor = Color.Red;

        Size = new Size(200, 200);
        
        Controls.Add(actionPanel);
    }

}
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q76pw.jpg)

Comment: The screenshot is correct, you just forgot about the borders.  Use the ClientSize property instead.

Comment: Thank you so mcuh! I realized that it is probably the borders but It's funny how much I have searched and how simple the fix actually is